# Python lstat gives different value then system stat

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the file-permission of a file on my windows computer. Depending on if I use the python way I always get 666 for all the files I have tested. If I use the system `stat -c %a` command I get a different response.

I have also tried the

```
$ stat -c %a dummy.txt
644
```

```
>>> import os
>>> print(oct(os.lstat("dummy.txt").st_mode))
0o100666
```

```
>>> import os
>>> os.access("dummy.txt", os.X_OK) 
True
```

I expected the response to be 0o100644 and is execute access to be False. Does anyone know why I get these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of file based functions inside the os module im sure. If you run os.stat(filename) you can always interprate the results.

http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html

```
$ touch dummy.txt
$ stat -c %a dummy.txt
644
```

os.stat returns 644

```
In [1]: import os                                                                                                                                                                             

In [2]: from stat import *                                                                                                                                                                    

In [3]: oct(os.stat("dummy.txt")[ST_MODE])                                                                                                                                                    
Out[3]: '0o100644'
```

another way to get permissions:

```
from os import popen                                                                                                                                                                  

cmd = "stat -c '%A %a %n' *"                                                                                                                                                          

fname = "dummy.txt" 
for i in popen(cmd): 
    p, m, n = i.split() 
    if n != fname: 
        continue 
    print(m) 
    break
```

output

```
644
```